# Utilização do Spring Security

Tags: java, java-ee

Pessoal estou usando o **spring** security em um projeto, me foi informado que eu devo pegar o driver jdbc e colocar na pasta lib do tomcat para que todo processo do spring funcione corretamente, pois seria o tomcat que iria fazer a conexão, com banco para o spring funcionar. Até ai tudo bem, o projeto com spring e tudo esta funcionando normal.

Eu peguei o .war do projeto e coloquei num servidor externo ele subiu normal, sem eu ter que por o driver jdbc la na pasta lib do tomcat.

***As perguntas são:***

- Eu preciso realmente colocar o driver lá, ou basta estar na lib do projeto?
- Se eu alugar um serviço de hospedagem comercial, vai estar compátivel com spring?

Answer (score 3):

Tudo depende de como a sua aplicação está estruturada. Problemas podem surgir devido a segurança de acesso implementada nos Classloaders do Java.

Se o seu aplicativo gerencia a conexão com o banco de dados, não há problemas em deixar o driver JDBC na sua lib, pois as classes serão gerenciadas pelo mesmo Classloader.

Entretanto, se você deixar as conexões a cargo do servidor de aplicação, o driver precisa ficar na lib do servidor, pois as classes presentes nessa lib serão gerenciadas por outro Classloader.

Note que quando falamos em um ambiente complexo de uma JVM, composto por vários Classloaders, muitas coisas que são verdadeiras e simples num programa Java comum passam a ser falsas e difíceis.

Por exemplo, quando há vários Classloaders, existe a possibilidade de haver várias cópias da mesma classe em memória, cujos atributos estáticos podem conter valores diferentes para cada Classloader. Isso causa muitos problemas.

Além disso, cada container monta uma Hierarquia de Classloaders para proteger suas próprias bibliotecas de equívocos e ataques de uma aplicação de terceiros e também para evitar que uma aplicação interfira na outra. Isso, por exemplo, permite que várias instâncias de uma mesma aplicação sejam "instaladas" numa mesma instância do container.

Veja como exemplo a [Hierarquia de Classloaders do Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html):

```
      Bootstrap
          |
       System
          |
       Common
      /      \
 Catalina   Shared
             /   \
        Webapp1  Webapp2 ...
```

Quando um programa Java usa ou importa uma classe pela primeira vez, o Classloader atual consulta os seus ancestrais de mais alto nível na hierarquia. No caso do Tomcat, se uma aplicação vai carregar a classe `Pessoa`, o Classloader dela primeiro verifica no `Shared`, que por sua vez verifica o `Commom`, que por sua vez verifica o `System`. Se a classe não existir no Classloader "pai", então o Classloader atual tenta carregar a classe e retorna uma resposta positiva ou negativa ao Classloader "filho", culminando num processo em cascata.

Um problema comum é colocar um framework como o Spring na lib `Shared`. Quando a aplicação inicia o Spring, ele é encontrado então no Classloader `Shared`. Porém, o Spring tentará carregar várias classes configuradas no XML. Quando ele solicita ao seu Classloader (`Shared`) para carregar a classe `Pessoa`, o Classloader **não** irá procurar a classe no Classloader "filho", ou seja, o Classloader da aplicação, justamente onde a classe está.

Essas regras não são exatamente rígidas, existem configurações que permitem alterar o comportamento do Classloader. Não é preciso ter medo deles, são apenas classes Java com implementações e lógicas específicas. O importante é entender o funcionamento.